# Multiply each value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict called `data` and it looks like this

```
data = {
    'active_rate': [95, 93, 92],
    'purchase_per_active': [643, 629, 611]
}
```

How to multiply each value of the key with the other value in the same dict? something like this,

```
[95*643, 93*629, 92*611]
```

My approach was to construct a dict for each key and single value from the list then compute the product and then clear the dict and continue, but it just gets the final value for both the keys.

**Code:**

```
def calculate(**kwargs):
    d = {}
    for key, value in kwargs.items():

        for item in value:
            d[key] = item

    return d


a = calculate(**data)
print(a) #  {'purchase_per_active': 611, 'active_rate': 92}
```

Comment: You are just assigning, not multiplying inside your second for loop

Comment: Can the dict only have two keys, or is the number variable?

Comment: Its variable. It can have any number of keys.

Answer (score 7):

```
[ar * ppa for ar, ppa in zip(data['active_rate'], data['purchase_per_active'])]
```

If you want to be more generic (as you imply in comments), you could do

```
[functools.reduce(operator.mul, xs, 1) for xs in zip(*data.values())]
```

but note that it ignores some items if the lists have different lengths.

Comment: What if we don't know the keys in dict? E.g dict comes from POST request or something like that.

Comment: That is a very unprecise question. What do you expect to happen if you get a POST dict like `{'w': [0], 'x': [1, 2], 'y':[3, 4, 5], 'z':[6, 7, 8]}`? A web application should usually know what POST keys are valid.

Comment: I just gave an example. Its for usecase in scientific application.

Comment: I updated the answer with a more generic expression.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution for the example you have given would be:

```
m1 = [data['active_rate'][i] * data['purchase_per_active'][i] for i in range(len(data['active_rate']))]
```

A more generic solution would be:

```
from numpy import prod
m2 = [prod(i) for i in zip(*data.values())]
```